NX Monorepo: how to use one maven wrapper (instead of one in each sub module)
Im using nx and each of my java apps has its own copy of mvnw, mvnw.cmd.
apps\
  java\
    app1\
      mvnw
      mvnw.cmd
    app2\
      mvnw
      mvnw.cmd

I would like to remove mvnw and mvnw.cmd from each project under app1\ and app2\ and place them in just one place in my monorepo how is this possible?
NX itself gives a hint that the parent project module can be used.
If I delete mvnw from app1 and use nx install app1 - I get this error.
 NX   ⚠️ You chose not to use the Maven wrapper from the parent module, but no wrapper was found in current child module
Where can mvnw be placed? I tried the root of the project but nx did not find it there.

Do you have a codebase to share so that we can test it out on the local?
